# Is earning from freelance writing for a sports arena which includes haram things halal?

Tags: halal-haram, profession

I'm doing a freelance job to earn enough to buy a laptop to help me with my studies.

My freelance writing job includes me writing about a sports arena in the US which include all sorts of haram things ranging from music to alcohol bars. My employer has instructed me to write articles in a way that would advertise the arena and make people consider to go watch the games and buy tickets in it.

Is advertising such a place haram? If yes then what should I do with the money I've already earned for writing a few articles already?

Answer (score 1):

Haram deeds have sin and Advertising for Haram deeds is cooperating in sin. Advertising for a sin business is cooperating in sin. Cooperating in sin is prohibited in the holy Quran:

> ...وَتَعَاوَنُوا عَلَى الْبِرِّ‌ وَالتَّقْوَىٰ ۖ وَلَا تَعَاوَنُوا
>   عَلَى الْإِثْمِ وَالْعُدْوَانِ ۚ وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ ۖ إِنَّ اللَّهَ
>   شَدِيدُ الْعِقَابِ
>
> ... And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but **do not cooperate in
>   sin and aggression**. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is severe in
>   penalty.
>   http://tanzil.net/#5:2

And we should know who provide for us is Allah and not the boss:

> أَمَّنْ هَـٰذَا الَّذِي يَرْ‌زُقُكُمْ إِنْ أَمْسَكَ رِ‌زْقَهُ ۚ بَل
>   لَّجُّوا فِي عُتُوٍّ وَنُفُورٍ‌
>
> Or who is it that could provide for you if He withheld His provision?
>   But they have persisted in insolence and aversion. http://tanzil.net/#67:21

What God has provided for you including laptop is in sky and you should ask it from God by dua. cannot God give you a laptop by Halal way?

> وَفِي السَّمَاءِ رِ‌زْقُكُمْ وَمَا تُوعَدُونَ
>
> And in the heaven is your provision and whatever you are promised.
>   http://tanzil.net/#51:22

The ruling about past income is that because this has been a Haram business so that business has not established in Islam and so you do not own the income. so this money is not yours at all and you should return it or have it by satisfaction of its real owner as a gift for example or if you cannot find the owner of a money you should pass it to a qualified scholar to spend it for Islamic purposes or pay it for charity by permission of qualified jurist ruler.

Reference: QA from [website of Imam Khamenei](http://www.leader.ir/)

Comment: How is this cooperation in sin? In that case even if, OP buys the laptop he/she is cooperating in a sin indirectly.

Comment: @BleedingFingers advertising for a sin business is cooperating in sin.

Comment: The business OP has mentioned is not all sin. It includes haram business and if OP isn't contributing/cooperationg/promoting that then I think it is permissible. More like working in restaurant which serves pig meat but one only serve cold drinks in that restaurant.

Comment: @BleedingFingers anyway advertising a whole business is promoting sin parts of it too. this ads attract more customer and when customer enters uses all services. what Islam thinks is important. not what you think. also there is not famine of business. why work in such business.  http://tanzil.net/#17:36

Comment: It's not what I think. I'm just logically speaking and trying to point out that maybe you're misconstruing the verses.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with it since you are not directly involved in those haram acts.

Make sure you're only writing about thing which are not haram i.e. about the game, player etc and not about alcohol, music and pubs therein.

It's act that directly promote an haram thing/idea/act that is forbidden/haram and so is the money earned from it.

Comment: http://tanzil.net/#17:36